# No tablet features working on X61 tablet with Ubuntu Gnome 14.10

Tags: gnome, touchpad, thinkpad, 14.10, wacom

recently installed Ubuntu gnome 14.10 from 14.04 LTS now none of the tablet features work stylus, screen rotation etc. I've installed all the Wacom packages that I could find in synaptic nothing seems to help. any advice would be greatly appreciated. This is all I'm getting for input devices

```
:~$ xinput -list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint                     id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ ThinkPad Extra Buttons                    id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Comment: I have found a Workaround here
[https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xf86-input-wacom/+bug/1392887)
but this did not work for my lenovo X41/lubuntu.
... still waiting for the official bugfix...